# Python Import Python File In Parent Directory

Tags: python, module, directory

I am working on a server, and I have a set of utilities that I want common to everything 'below' and 'beside' in the directory structure. It looks like this:

```
Server/
    server.py
    serverutils.py
    games/
        gamehandle.py
        __init__.py
```

I was wondering how I could import serverutils.py from gamehandle.py. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
I looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder), and the answer I was looking for wasn't there. I solved my problem by placing an empty `__init__.py` file in the Server/ folder.

Comment: A similar question was asked, and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: You need to make `Server` a package by giving it an `__init__.py` as well, and placing it in a directory on your `sys.path`.

Comment: @Guilherme yes, I looked at that, but couldn't figure it out

Comment: @BrenBarn I decided to do that, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
import os
import imp

serverutils = imp.load_source("serverutils",os.path.join("..",'serverutils.py'))
```

or directly the full path, because the previous depend on where you launch you script from. The easier in server is to have a param file with the full path.

```
serverutils = imp.load_source("serverutils",full_path_to_serverutils_script)
```

Comment: That might work, but I figured it out by placing an empty  `__init__.py` file in Server/. Thanks though